Python Regex for chess move parsing
Following conditions should be considered:

the target square needs to be give in full length (a-h and 1-8 board coordinates)
Exception is castling which is noted in traditional castling notation (O-O, O-O-O).

Fill words like takes or goes to are optional.

on is optional if the coordinates of the attacking piece are specified else on makes no sense.

If pieces or fill words are written out (Rook, goes to, king, captures), these will need to be buffered by whitespaces. Also a whitespace is not required if the word is located at the beginning or end of the input string. If the piece is abbreviated to a single character, there is no need for a following whitespace.
(Nf3 -> no whitespace required; knight f3 -> yes whitespace; Nxd4 -> no white required; N takes d4 -> whitespaces required on each side of takes)

If the piece is abbreviated it needs to be a capital letter to distinguish it from board coordinates (B for bishop and b coordinate).

If both coordinates of the attacking piece are given (e2e4 is Pe2e4), or the piece is a pawn, the piece does not have to be given (e4 is Pe4).

Check and checkmate are optional and also need to be buffered by whitespaces if not abbreviated (yes Rd8+, yes Rd8 check, yes Rd8 +, no Rd8check).


EXAMPLE INPUTS:
Knight on g1 goes to f3
b captures a8 =q checkmate
Ra1e1+
rook 2 to f8 with check
O-O-O#

Possible structuring of regex:
[Knight ][on ][g1][ to ][f3][ with check] -> 'Knight to f3' not possible!
[Knight][ on][ g1][ to ][f3][ with check] -> 'Ng1f3' not possible!
[Knight][ on ][g1][ to ][f3][ with check] -> 'Knight g1 to f3' not possible!

This is what I have come up with this far:
r'(Knight|knight|N)?( on )?[a-h]?[1-8]?( to | takes | captures )?[a-h][1-8](Q|=Q| queen)?( check| checkmate)?'

There are a lot of double whitespaces and no whitespaces where they are needed.
I'm sure there is a better way of doing this ...

here is a download link for the full project: http://0x0.st/XkcG.zip

i would split the parsing to two stages, first to determine if the input is valid standard notation, if so no need to do anything, if not then convert to standard notation, second stage would be regular standard notation parsing where you don't even need regex. mixing the two is imo bad design

thats a good idea

my attempt https://regex101.com/r/GzSiJ2/1 the spaces doesn't really matter, just human convenience

Try (in freespacing mode):
^ # start of string
(?: # list of moves
    (?: # option 1; regular move
        ( # list of figures
            [Kk]night|N|n|
            [Bb]ishop|B|b|
            [Rr]ook|R|r|
            [Kk]ing|K|k|
            [Qq]ueen|Q|q|
            [Pp]awn|P|p
        )
        ( # possible "from"s
            (?:\ on\ )?
            [a-h][1-8]
            |
            \ [1-8]
        )?
        ( # possible "to" prefixes
            \ (?:(?:goes\ )?to|takes|captures)\ 
        )?
        [a-h][1-8] # to
        ( # list of figures at destination
            \ 
            (?:
                =? # optionally preceeded by "=" for captures (?)
                (?: # list of figures
                    [Kk]night|N|n|
                    [Bb]ishop|B|b|
                    [Rr]ook|R|r|
                    [Kk]ing|K|k|
                    [Qq]ueen|Q|q|
                    [Pp]awn|P|p
                )
            )
        )?
        ( # result of move
            (?:\ with)\ check|\ checkmate|\+
        )?
    )# end regular move
    |
    (?:
        O-O(?:-O)?[+#]?
        ) # option 2 casteling
    )
$

normal mode becomes:
^(?:(?:([Kk]night|N|n|[Bb]ishop|B|b|[Rr]ook|R|r|[Kk]ing|K|k|[Qq]ueen|Q|q|[Pp]awn|P|p)((?:\ on\ )?[a-h][1-8]|\ [1-8])?(\ (?:(?:goes\ )?to|takes|captures)\ )?[a-h][1-8](\ (?:=?(?:[Kk]night|N|n|[Bb]ishop|B|b|[Rr]ook|R|r|[Kk]ing|K|k|[Qq]ueen|Q|q|[Pp]awn|P|p)))?((?:\ with)\ check|\ checkmate|\+)?)|(?:O-O(?:-O)?[+#]?))$

See: regex101

what about regular castle or castle to checkmate ? just teasing

@Kazz dont know chess move notation to this extend - how would these be denoted? i think it would be straight forward to add them into option 2/3?

O-O king side castle or O-O-O queen side castle, postfix # means check, postfix + means checkmate

@Kazz thanks! Inclueded these as well as other pieces.
